# Adding an Item to Another List When Drag and Drop in React Sortable HOC

Tags: reactjs, sorting, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm working on a React project and I'm using react-sortable-hoc for implementing drag-and-drop functionality. Currently, I have multiple lists, and I'm able to reorder items within the same list. However, I'd like to know if it would be possible to add an item to another list when I drag and drop it with react-sortable-hoc.

Additionally, I found this related video that might help:
for example add item 0 to the list 0 and drag and drop
[image: example]

Here's the code I'm working with:
[the code](https://codesandbox.io/s/81v9lxk392)